# Alternative for DELETE and UPDATE statements in SPARK

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am converting Java batches to spark using **Java** language.

Existing code of the application contains many delete and update statements using *JDBC*.

As per information given on various stackoverflow answers and on other websites, currently *sparkSQL* doesn't have any functionality to run **DELETE** or **UPDATE** queries.

I can use **JDBC** in my spark code, but won't it degrade application's performance?

Is there any other alternative for using **DELETE/UPDATE** statememts in SPARK?

I am using **SPARK version : 2.3.0**

I am not able to find any information regarding same, hence asking this informative question.

Comment: Just wait until you try using JDBC in your spark code to delete or update. The usual approach is to create a new table using a select with a filter to remove the rows you want deleted and update the rows you want updated from the original table.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch okay so you are suggesting it is fine to use JDBC in spark code? I will try it for sure Thanks.

Comment: I'm really teasing you, using jdbc won't suddenly make update and delete work. But try it by all means.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch okay :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the update queries are very complex(multiple joins, inner queries and many conditions) in current application that is the reason i am not sure if the general approach for update which you have mentioned in your first comment will work.

Comment: Which database are you connecting to?

Comment: @Rony oracle Database.

Comment: So why do you want to use spark for data manipulation in Oracle ? Just use plain old sqls. Spark wont be faster when operating on Oracle, rather it will be slower. It works for hdfs only.

Comment: @Rony there are many examples where spark is used with oracle and other databases as well, spark provides parallel processing and in memory computations which decreases the TAT. I have used spark with oracle and it has been faster.

Comment: I see..I didn't know that. Thanks.